# Use Cloud Storage API upload files

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, temporary-files

I am trying to populate a bucket on Google Cloud Services, but the python API client library that I've been using, and that has been treating me very well, doesn't seem to work for uploading files.

The API is [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/storage/v1) and is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/index.html)

When I try to use the `storage.objects.insert` I get a response with an error that says:
`"reason": "wrongUrlForUpload"
"message": "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/"`

I did some experimenting.  I found out that I need to pass in a file name, but my data is in a string, not on my file system.  I'm creating a file name with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, and passing that name in.  `tempfile` creates a file like `/tmp/tmpOGyQY1`, but the library doesn't like it unless it can determine a file type.  If the file name has an extension, then it works.  Is there a way I can create a tempfile with an extension?  Or is there some other way I can inform the library of the file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the piece I was missing was to set `suffix=".csv"` when I create the tempfile

Comment: I am having a similar problem (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915526/httperror-400-when-trying-to-upload-pdf-file-on-google-cloud-storage/36922447#36922447). Do you have an example of your code to share?