# HttpError 400 when trying to upload pdf file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am setting up a service that:

1. receives an email with an attachment file
2. uploads this file to cloud storage
3. uses that file as a source for further processing

I arrived at step 2 where the error is occurring. I am using the discovery API for Google services to authenticate. Mine is a simple flask application and below is the incoming email handler.

**handle_incoming_email.py**

```
__author__ = 'ciacicode'

import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()


class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
        # upload attachment to cloud storage
        filename = 'any'
        try:
            attachment = mail_message.attachments
            filename = attachment[0].filename
            body = str(attachment[0].payload)
        except IndexError:
            print len(attachment)

        storage = build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
        req = storage.objects().insert(bucket='ocadopdf', body={'body': body, 'contentType': 'application/pdf', 'name': str(filename), 'contentEncoding': 'base64'})
        resp = req.execute()
        return resp


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

After I send an email to the service I see the following error in the logs:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/ocadopdf/o?alt=json returned
>   "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL
>   path beginning with /upload/">

I understand that the information is not POSTed to the right endpoint and that is missing a URL parameter, but the more I dig in the Google documentation the less I can find something clear on how to use .build from the discovery module to add the URL path before the service 'storage'.

-- Update with solution --

```
    file = cStringIO.StringIO()
    file.write(body)
    media = http.MediaIoBaseUpload(file, mimetype='application/pdf')
    storage = build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    req = storage.objects().insert(bucket='ocadopdf', body={'name': str(filename), 'contentEncoding': 'base64'}, media_body=media)
    resp = req.execute()
    return resp`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build invocation looks correct to me. This [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-python-samples) provides a good reference on how to upload a file to GCS as a new object. Instead of passing a file handle to MediaIoBaseUpload, you can pass a io.BytesIO containing the object contents as described in the [MediaIoBaseUpload](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html) documentation

Comment: Hi Angus, unfortunately the example only shows how to work with files on local machines. The email attachment is a google object, not a regular python file object. So far the problem hasn't been with the content of the body, but with the endpoint call itself.

Comment: Correct - the second link shows a usage of MediaIoUpload with io.BytesIO and arbitrary bytes, but could just as easily be StringIO, etc.

Comment: Thanks to you @Angus Davis I got it working  with the changes I posted above, even if I cannot successfully open the pdf after upload. I think though this has to do with the encoding so this question per se is answered. When error 400 like this shows up it points to the lack of a media_body parameter filled with a proper file stream object.